ESLint no muestra errores en archivos .vue y está ignorando archivos de prueba en un proyecto Vue
Quiero implementar ESLint (v 9.3.0) en mi proyecto Vue, pero no está mostrando los errores (con error lens) en mis archivos .vue; además, también está arrojando errores de mis archivos de prueba ('./src/testing/**/*.test.js'). ¿Qué necesito hacer para lograr lo que quiero?
Este es mi código:
import globals from 'globals';
import pluginJs from '@eslint/js';
import pluginVue from 'eslint-plugin-vue';

export default [
  {
    languageOptions: { globals: globals.browser },
    ignores: ['./src/testing/**/*.test.js'],
    rules: { 'no-unused-vars': 'error', semi: ['warn', 'always'] },
  },
  pluginJs.configs.recommended,
  ...pluginVue.configs[('flat/essential', 'flat/recommended')],
];

Estas son mis dependencias de desarrollo:
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.3.0",
    "@quasar/vite-plugin": "^1.7.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.0.4",
    "@vitest/coverage-v8": "^1.6.0",
    "@vitest/ui": "^1.6.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "eslint": "^9.3.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.1",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^16.6.2",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.26.0",
    "globals": "^15.2.0",
    "husky": "^9.0.11",
    "prettier": "3.2.5",
    "sass": "^1.33.0",
    "vite": "^5.2.0",
    "vitest": "^1.6.0"
  }

Esta es la documentación que estoy usando como referencia: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/ignore
Agradezco cualquier ayuda de antemano.
¡Déjenme saber si necesitan más asistencia o modificaciones!
